# HTML5 Cache Manifest and Content types

Tags: apache, http, html, content-type

i am reading [Dive into HTML5: Offline web apps: Cache manifest](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/offline.html#manifest)

> ... but it must be served with the
>   content type text/cache-manifest. If
>   you are running an Apache-based web
>   server, you can probably just put an
>   AddType directive in the .htaccess
>   file at the root of your web directory
>
> `AddType text/cache-manifest
>   .manifest`

if i dont add this what will happen? is the content type so important? i did a search for `AddType` in `httpd.conf`. but i dont see `content-type` for say `html`, `js`, `images` etc. it dont seem all that important after all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that if you don't have the content type set correctly the browsers will refuse to treat it as a manifest file, similar to the well known Firefox problem where [stylesheets get ignored if served with a plain text MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Web_Developer_FAQ#My_style_sheet_doesn.e2.80.99t_work!_Why.3f).

The content types of your Apache server are possibly not in httpd.conf, they are usually stored in another configuration file mime.types (by default, [though it can be changed](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#typesconfig)).

Comment: I add mine straight to httpd.conf. You can also add it to .htaccess file in the local web directory.